# How to export KML file with JAK library or libkml -java?

Tags: java, xml, kml, jak

I use KML object in java. I want to export this object to file. I try to write this with JAK library,with the function KML.marshal() but it not successFul.
I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/marshaller/NamespacePrefixMapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.createMarshaller(Kml.java:642)
    at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.marshal(Kml.java:682)
    at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.marshal(Kml.java:759)
    at com.nice.nicetrack.KMLGenerator.toKML(KMLGenerator.java:141)
    at com.nice.nicetrack.KMLGenerator.main(KMLGenerator.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

I don't want use XML or String format. Only KMl object!!
please- help me!!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[JAK](https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml) depends on the Java Architecture for XML Binding ([JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html)) for the underlying XML serialization. KML is an XML format so you must add the JAXB jars to your classpath.

```
jaxb-api-2.2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
```

These dependencies can be found in the POM.XML for the project.
https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml/blob/master/pom.xml

If you use maven to build you can add the jaxb entries directly to your pom.xml file, but they should be downloaded automatically if you add the *JavaAPIforKml* entry as shown below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.micromata.jak</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaAPIforKml</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, you can directly search for the jars in Central Maven repository:
https://search.maven.org/#browse

**UPDATE:**

JAK 2.2.1 was released in 2014 when this question was originally posted. [Geotools](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/extension/xsd/kml.html) library which is an active project supports parsing KML from Java.

Comment: The versions you point to are quite old already. Also, JAXB is now distributed via the Central Maven repo, it is not recommended to use download.java.net.